# Display NSNumber In Label

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to display an NSNumber from an array with keys into an UILabel. Here is my current code: `marblesNeeded.text = [[[records objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey: @"marblesneeded"] intValue];`

I also get the error:
`warning: Semantic Issue: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'NSString *' from 'int'`

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to create an NSString to set the text of a UILabel.

```
marblesNeeded.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[[[records objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey: @"marblesneeded"] intValue]];
```

In the format %i denotes that you will be providing an integer value after the format.

Edit:

As some comments have noted NSNumber does have a stringValue, it does work but is not my personal preference because it gives you little control as to the format of the string. Consider this example.

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.25];
NSLog(@"%@",number.stringValue);  // Will print 3.25
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",number.intValue]); // Will print 3
```

Since the question envolved printing an intValue this more explicit format may be necessary.

Comment: You can also use [myNumber stringValue]

Comment: No need to grab the int value NSNumber should know how to print itself e.g. `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[records objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey: @"marblesneeded"];`

Comment: @sosborn comment is even cooler but if your format was a bit more complicated it's handy to know my comment

Comment: If you wanted more control over formatting then you could use an `NSNumberFormatter` this would give you localised formats etc, which makes for localising your app easier.

Comment: Very true, NSNumberFormatter does give you the most control over the format used to create a string. I didn't mention that because of the context of the question. The question is about displaying the value of the key "marblesneeded", it seems unlikely that there will be 2.3 marbles needed or that there will be 2.30 Euros of marbles needed; It seemed to me he just wanted to display the int value of the NSNumber.

Answer (score 4):

```
marblesNeeded.text = [[[records objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey: @"marblesneeded"] stringValue];
```